# Adding and removing buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently developing a simple webpage for a school assignment and I was wondering it is possible to create a button that will add a button, also a button beside it to remove the button?

Basically a button called "Add Button" where if you click on it, a button with the same size(can be named anything appropriate with no functions required). no matter how many times I click it, more buttons will be added e.g. button1, button2, button3 etc. Also, next to "Add Button" button is a button called "Remove Button" where it removes the buttons desendingly e.g. from button3, button2, then button1

Comment: Please share the research you have done for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this? Change the increment slightly.

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   button{
     height:100px;
     width: 80px;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 5px 4px;
   }
  #mainButtons button{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    }
   </style>


<div id="mainButtons">
 <button onclick="addButton()">Make Button</button>
 <button onclick="removeButton()">Remove Button</button>
</div>
</br>
<div id="que"></div>

<script>
var increment = 0;
function addButton(){
 $("#que").append($("<button id='btn"+(increment++)+"'>This is Button"+ (increment)+"</button>"));
}

function removeButton(){
  $("#btn"+(increment-1)).remove();
  increment--;
}
</script>
```

Comment: ..basically its decremented after the remove. ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark my answer if you like as accepted. Also, might have to put some kind of if statement on the remove so it won't remove if a button doesn't exist else it will keep decrementing

Comment: Yea I realised it turned negative as I kept clicking remove but nonetheless I'd still mark your answer as very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use append() jquery function.
This is example :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="add_button">add</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="delete_button">delete</button>
    <div class="result">

    </div>
```

Jquery :

```
var start = 0;
        $(document).on("click","#add_button",function(){
            start++;
  $(".result").append($('<button id="add_button">Add'+start+'</button>').addClass('button'+start));
});
        $(document).on("click","#delete_button",function(){
            start--;
  $(".result").find('#add_button').each(function(index, el) {
    $('.button'+start).remove();
  });;
});
```

Js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/p8y672oL/

Comment: Actually its working as I would imagine it. Thank you.

Comment: Your wellcome  :-) .

Comment: I added around 5 buttons and tried to remove them, apparently not all buttons were removed

Comment: Because that is example :-D , you can imagine for next :-)

Answer (score 0):

Must they be numbered?  If not you can append the buttons and use jQuery's last() and remove() functions without the need of an increment/decrement variable.

```
    <div class="button-test">
        <button type="button" id="add-button">Add Button</button>
        <button type="button" id="remove-button">Remove Last Button</button>
        <div id="new-buttons"></div>
    </div>


    <script>
        $('#add-button').on('click', function () {
            $('#new-buttons').append($('<button>', {
                'type': 'button',
                'class': 'temp',
                'text': 'new button'
            }));
        });

        $('#remove-button').on('click', function () {
            $('#new-buttons button.temp').last().remove();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Not exactly but will keep this in one of my many running codes. Thanks!